# Inserting dynamic excel sheet into confluence

Tags: confluence

I'm attempting to add a spreadsheet to a Confluence page using "Insert content > Office Excel." However, this method only inserts the spreadsheet contents, and does not retain the interactive features such as dropdowns and graphs. These dynamic elements rely on hidden data within the same spreadsheet. When modifying one dropdown, the data in subsequent dropdowns updates automatically. Unfortunately, once uploaded to Confluence, the contents become static, preventing dropdown values from being changed. I'm seeking a solution to retain interactivity. Additionally, I'm open to suggestions on alternative ways to present the data from the CSV file.

[image: Insert content into Confluence]